# scala call mkString while manipulating elements

Tags: scala

I am wondering what the best approach to converting an array of elements to String is when I want to do something specific to the elements. For example say I have

```
case class A(x: Int, y: Int)
val list = List(A(2, 3), A(4, 2), A(5, 1))
```

Now say I wanted for example to convert this to a comma separated list of only the x values. ie, "2, 4, 2". Is there a way to achieve this with mkString?

And a related question is how to handle lists within lists. So say we have:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: Int, bs: List(B))
case class B(z: Int)
```

and the following list:

```
val list = List(A(2, 3, List(B(4), B(2))), A(4, 2, List()), A(5, 1, List(B(3))))
```

and I want to output parts of A combined with say the first element in B to produce something like: "2:4, "4:", "5:3".

Is there a way of achieving this with mkString or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks
Des

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can map first and then make string:

```
val remapped = myList map { 
  case A(x, y) => "%s:%s" format (x, y)
}

remapped mkString (",")
```

this produces "1:2, 2:5" formatting. If you just want comma delimited then you could flatMap:

```
val remapped = myList flatMap{
  case A(x, y) => List(x, y)
}

remapped mkString (",")
```

which will give you "1, 2, 2, 5".

Can you directly do this with just `mkString`? No, I don't believe so unless you overwrote the `toString` method of `A` like so:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: Int){
  override def toString() = "%s:%s" format (x, y)
}
```

**For nested lists**

You'll have to get a little more creative with the `unapply`:

```
myList map {
  case A(x, _, head :: _) => "%s:%s" format (x, head.z)
  case A(x, _, Nil) => x toString ()
}
```

wherein you're extracting the first item of the nested list of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to transform your values like this:

First:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: Int)
val list = List(A(2, 3), A(4, 2), A(5, 1))
list map(_.x) mkString(",")

>> res0: String = 2,4,5
```

Second:

```
case class B(z: Int)
case class A(x: Int, y: Int, bs: List[B])

val list = List(
  A(2, 3, List(B(4), B(2))),
  A(4, 2, List()),
  A(5, 1, List(B(3))))

list.map(e => List(e.x) ++ e.bs.map(_.z).take(1))
    .map(_.mkString(":"))
    .mkString(", ")

>> res0: String = 2:4, 4, 5:3
```

I hope that helps.